# Android Studio is not detecting code changes when deploy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I change the code, change is not reflected to the APK or to the debugged app.
What I did so far:

- Deleted .gradle folder
- Reinstalled Android Studio and also a new canary version
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Deleted the source code and fetched again from repo
- Restarted laptop
- Enabled Always install with package manager
- Before launch is already Gradle-aware Make

I am on Macos 12.6.2.
There is a known issue with the MacOs:
*Incremental updates are not applied due to an issue with Gradle file watching on projects saved under /System/Volumes/Data*
But my project is not under this folder.

I suspect that this problem started after the Macos update.
It sometimes works for the first time but does not work after that.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nelson Osacky, Gradle Engineer helped me in identifying the issue. He pointed me to the plugins used in the project. Thanks to him!

'gradle.plugin.com.github.sgtsilvio.gradle:android-retrofix:0.4.1' plugin was the root cause for the issue. When I removed it, everything worked fine.